# Convert javascript json object into Java json object

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert the following script into java json, however I'm failing at `"aTargets", [0]`

I'm not sure how to create an array with just zero.

Script to be converted,

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

My Java

```
 public JSONObject getOptions() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("aoColumnDefs", new JSONArray()
                //Failing here
                .put(new JSONObject("bSortable", "false", "aTargets", "[0]")));
                                                          //Failing here too
        json.put("aaSorting", new JSONArray(new JSONArray(1, 'asc')));
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that is how you use JSONObject. See here http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html for constructor summary.

Comment: What you have in your first script block is not a "JSON object." It is JavaScript using literal syntax. JSON is a serialization scheme using a subset of JavaScript literal syntax.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, I completely over looked my code.

Comment: Ah, Thanks JAAulde, I didn't realize there was a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but I believe it's correct:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("aoColumnDefs", new JSONArray()
  .put(new JSONObject("bSortable", "false", "aTargets", new JSONArray().put(0))));
json.put("aaSorting", new JSONArray().put(new JSONArray().put(1, "asc"));
```